# Parsing text with linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have such text

```
      5       1     .021   -56.6   -5      0.4    -5      0.    
   -.05     -.1     .05     -.1     .05      .1    -.05      .1       
   YESA      1.                                                       
  .8507  .84993
```

and I must get

```
      5       1     .021   -56.6   -5      0.4   -5      0.    
   -.05     -.1     .05     -.1     .05      .1    -.05      .1       
   YESA      1.     0.       0.      0.      0.      0.      0.               
  .8507  .84993     0.       0.      0.      0.      0.      0.
```

but when i use next construction

```
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
         while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
            string[] vector = temp.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < vector.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat(ConvertString(vector[i])));
        }
```

i get first text without changes.

Comment: it is unclear what the question is... or indeed why a lot of the code here is messing with commas and nil-characters since that seems  completely unrelated to what you are trying to do. Can you clarify: what is the spacing here? spaces to align? or tabs? or...?

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question

Comment: in text I have a sequence of number , in place where number is misses I have a space .And I must swap each space to zero. In each line I have 7 numbers

Comment: Getting closer. But how are the fields specified (Width) and how do you get from `0.4.5794-5` to `0.4.5` and `-5` ? Most fields seem to be right-aligned but in this one it's unclear.

Comment: i have mistake, and I correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would even bother to parse the floats.

It looks like you just have lines of items (that may or may not be floats) and you have to complete the lines to 8 items. Like

```
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var words = line.Split( new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach(string w in words)
                Console.Write("{0,6}", w);

            // filling out
            for (int i = words.Length; i < 8; i++)
                Console.Write("{0,6}", "0.");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use two auxiliary function

```
private float ConvertToFloat(string line)//to check integer or float number
        {
            string temp = "";

            if (line[line.Length - 1] == ',' || line[0] == ',')
            {
                temp = line.Replace(',', '\0');
                return float.Parse(temp);
            }
            else
                return float.Parse(line);

        }
        private string ConvertString(string line)//change '.' to ','
        {
            return line.Replace('.', ',');
        }
```